# The most neat way to remove all but the last element with the same key from a sorted std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of structures {key; value}, sorted by key:

`{ {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2} }`

I need to erase all but the last elements with the same key. The result should be:

`{ {0, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2} }`

What is the most neat way to do this? Which STL algorithms can I use? Apparently, this task doesn't fit remove-erase idiom.

Comment: Should this be an ordered associative container like `std::map` instead of `std::vector`? Seems like you're using the wrong container.

Comment: std::copy from the vector into std::set, erase the vector, then copy everything back into the vector? No idea if it the most performance-efficient method though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I words, the algorithm needed would be:

- iterate the container backwards
- if you encoutner a new key, leave the element,
- if you encoutner a key you already had, remove the element.

in code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct S { int key; int value; };

int main() {
  std::vector<S> vec{ {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2} };

  auto lastKey = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
  auto rLast = std::remove_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [&lastKey](S const& s) -> bool {
    if (s.key == lastKey) return true;
    lastKey = s.key;
    return false;
  });
  vec.erase(begin(vec),rLast.base());

  for (auto& s : vec) {
    std::cout << '{' << s.key << ',' << s.value << '}';
  }
}
```

Or using `std::unique` as recommended in the other answer:

```
auto rLast = std::unique(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend() [](S const& s1, S const& s2) {
  return s1.key == s2.key;
});
vec.erase(vec.begin(), rLast.base());
```

Answer (score 8):

A naive but efficient solution is to iterate over the vector, copying the relevant elements into a new vector.

An alternative is to use `std::unique` (with an appropriate predicate).  As you want to preserve the *last* element in each group, you'd need to use a reverse iterator.

Comment: @juanchopanza: `set` doesn't have `operator[]`. Did you mean `map`?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Oh wow, what they say about not enough coffee is true. Sorry about the nonsense.

Comment: One possibility would be `std::set<std::pair<int, int> > uniques{input.rbegin(), input.rend()};` Concise, though not necessarily the most efficient.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I was wondering about such a solution. But is there any guarantee that the input sequence is processed in order?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, I think so -- I don't see any other way to meet the requirement for linear complexity on sorted input.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe more concisely than `std::unique`? (See example of that in my answer)

Comment: Unique preserves one element from each *consecutive* run of elements.

Comment: @BillyONeal: The OP has stated that the elements have already been sorted appropriately.

Comment: @Oli: I wasn't saying this was wrong. I was clarifying Jerry's answer -- that is, that passing an unsorted range to unique is perfectly well defined. Just not often desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an `std::map` the problem just disappears:

```
std::map<int, int> theMap;
// insert the elements of { {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2} }
theMap[0] = 1;
theMap[0] = 2;
theMap[1] = 1;
theMap[1] = 2;
theMap[1] = 3;
theMap[2] = 1;
theMap[2] = 2;
// result: { {0, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2} }
```